# jQuery load a foreign web page with xmlHttpReq and parse the resulting variable as a DOM document

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, document

Trying to figure out how to do this:

Within the `$(doculent).ready` function I use this code to read a web page from another server:

```
var qString = "Newsletters/Legacy/somewebpage.html";

        var xmlHttpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttpReq.open("GET", qString, false);
        xmlHttpReq.send(null);
        var answer = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
```

Now I try to access the DOM Document elements from that answer variable:

```
var a = $('answer.lnkbuttontext:first').text();
        $('#theMenu').html = a;
```

Where elements from class lnkbuttontext are links and I want both the link and the likn text.

Trying with ...`text()` returns empty string and trying with ...`html()` returns undefined.

I must be wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make cross-domain XHRs unless the server you're requesting data from includes the proper `Access-Control` headers in its response. Without those headers you will have to use a proxy to make the request.

Comment: Ah,fine. And... How do i add those headers? At server level? At page level? What is the sybtax?